# About Lie algebras and the corresponding lie groups

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I want to prove the following proposition about lie groups and Lie algebras:

Let $G$ be a **connected** Lie group, and $\mathfrak{g}$ be the Lie algebra of G.
Then, the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is solvable if and only if $G$ has a subnormal series  whose factor groups are all Abelian, with any term being **connected** lie subgroup of G
(i.e. $G$ has a sequence $\{ G_i \}$ such that $G_i$ is a connected Lie subgroup of $G$ and is a normal subgroup of $G_{i-1}$, and the quotient $G_{i-1} / G_i$ is abelian), where the definition of "$\mathfrak{g}$ is solvable" is the one using a series of ideals $\{ \mathfrak{g}_i \}$.

But I can't prove the part that $\mathfrak{g}_{i-1} / \mathfrak{g}_i$ is Abelian iff $G_{i-1} / G_i$ is Abelian. (Remark: $G_i$ is generated by the image of $\mathfrak{g}_i$ under the exponential map.)

How do I prove this? I want to know the way to prove directly, not to prove $\mathfrak{g}_{i-1} / \mathfrak{g}_i$ is the Lie algebra of  $G_{i-1} / G_i$.

Comment: I don't see a way to prove this "directly" without just doing all of the work of showing that $\mathfrak{g}_{i-1}/\mathfrak{g}_i$ is the Lie algebra of $G_{i-1}/G_i$.

Comment: Moreover this is the general idea, to "reduce" the problem to the Lie algebra level. Usually this way, using (linear) algebra, is much easier than the direct way.

Comment: In this situation, is $G_{i-1}/G_i$ a Lie group or closed subgroup necessarily? To say honestly, I know only quotient Lie groups by discrete normal subgroups. So I don't want to use Callum's way...... but I will learn them. Thank you.